# Акселерометр в Win32

Tags: windows, драйвер

Люди, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть варианты работы с этим устройством в Windows7?
 Акселерометр установлен на планшетном компьютере, не виден в списке датчиков(так что Sensor API, кажется, неприменим. Если есть возможность как-то использоваь его, буду очень рад), но есть драйвер bma150.sys (к одноименному акселерометру фирмы Bosch).

Существует ли какой-нибудь специальный интерфейс для работы с такого рода устройствами, или придётся работать напрямую с драйвером? Если вариант 2, то как примерно это будет выглядеть?

Я так понимаю, с драйверами в отсутствие спецAPI работают через DeviceIOControl? Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать?

Answer (score 2):

Навскидку нагуглил. Оно?

[Graphing Accelerometer Data in Windows 7: Sample Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463482)

Там по ссылкам исходники и какие-то "white papers".

Comment: Да, это я видел. По ходу, там как раз через SensorAPI сделано, только под .NETом. Не работает =( Хотя вполне может быть, что достаточно где-нибудь в настройках поковыряться.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Да, с драйверами работают в основном через DeviceIOControl. Чтобы начать что-то конкретно делать, Вам нужно узнать API драйвера, с которым Ваше приложение собирается работать. Если драйвер предоставляет [интерфейс](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/wiisensor.aspx), необходимый для Sensor API, то устройство должно подцепиться автоматически; можно посмотреть настройки в devmgmt.msc, возможно где-то выставить галочки и т.п. Если нет, то обычно шаги такие:

1. CreateFile
2. DeviceIOControl
3. CloseHandle

Пример: [Calling DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363147(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо!
Плохо только, что никакой документации по драйверу я совсем не нашел :( Остается ждать или попробовать связаться с разработчиками...